# Yup and Formik Validation in React

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have a condition that a certain field is required if the value is either '1', '2', '3', '4'. How can you do this? Pls check my code below

```
 travelDate: yup.string().when('planeAvailable', {
    is: '1' || '2' || '3' || '4',
    then: yup.string().required('Choose Date'),
  }),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
 travelDate: yup.string().when('planeAvailable', {
    is: val => ['1', '2', '3', '4'].includes(val)
    then: yup.string().required('Choose Date'),
  }),
```

[doc](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema)

> `is` conditions are strictly compared (`===`) ***if you want to use a different form of equality you can provide a function like***: `is: (value) => value == true`.